# MongoDB schema design for multpile choice questions and answers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, orm

I'm not skilled in MongoDB designing and I need help in designing a DB. What is the best structure for Storing **Questions having answer choices** and **Answers from candidate**?

-Each candidate will get a set of 12 questions if the candidate fails in the first exam they can attend 2 more exams. So on each exam candidate should get different set of questions each time.

-Answer by each candidate for each test will have to be recorded with the score out of 12 as each question set is 12.

Comment: have you started modeling the schema in mongoose or need to start from scratch?

Comment: I haven't created the schema yet just created stub data of questions collection.Im thinking like a question collection will have question object containing question,question image and an array with choices.that's it till now

Comment: Ok good. Let me add an answer to this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have created a mongoose schema for each required details. You can take help from it. I have analyzed a bit your requirements and adding models for many schemas, first question schema, exported as a model

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import { AnswerOptionSchema } from './answer-option-schema';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

export const QuestionSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  question: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 10,
    maxlength: 1000,
  },
  answerOptions: {
    type: [AnswerOptionSchema],
    default: undefined,
    validate: {
      validator: function(value: any) {
        return value && value.length === 4;
      },
      message: 'Answer options should be 4.'
    }
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});

export const Question = mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);
```

and here in the `QuestionSchema`, I have embedded an `AnswerOptionSchema` as

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';

export const AnswerOptionSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  optionNumber: {
    type: Number
  },
  answerBody: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 200,
  },
  isCorrectAnswer: { // you can store the correct answer with question id in another model.
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
}, {
  _id: false
});
```

With the help of these schemas, I have created a `QuestionSetSchema` to add a set of question schema as

```
import { Schema } from "mongoose";
import { QuestionSchema } from "./question-schema";
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

export const QuestionSetSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  questionSet: {
    type: [QuestionSchema],
    validate: {
      validator: function(value: any) {
        return value.length === 12;
      },
      message: 'Question set must be 12.'
    }
  },
}, {
  timestamps: true
});

export const QuestionSet = mongoose.model('QuestionSet', QuestionSetSchema);
```

Now prepared with the question, answer options and the set, now need to design the candidate schema,

```
import { Schema } from "mongoose";
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

export const CandidateSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String, // you can store other candidate related information here.
  totalAttempt: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
    validate: {
      validator: function(value: number) {
        return value === 3;
      },
      message: 'You have already done three attempts.'
    }
  },
  candidateQuestionAnswers: {
    type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    ref: 'CandidateQuesAnswer'
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});

export const Candidate = mongoose.model('Candidate', CandidateSchema);
```

Here, you will notice, I am also calculating the totalAttempt of the candidate and the answers for each set given by him in the `CandidateQuesAnswer` model. This model has the structure like

```
import { Schema } from "mongoose";

export const CandidateQuesAnswerSchema = new Schema({
  candidate: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Candidate'
  },
  questionSet: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'QuestionSet'
  },
  questionAnswers: {
    type: [Number] // You can add answer schema
  },
  totalScore: {
    type: Number
  },
  isPassed: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});

CandidateQuesAnswerSchema.pre('save', function updateTotalScore(next) {
  // update total score of the candidate here based on the correct questionAnswers and
  // questionSet.
  next();
});

CandidateQuesAnswerSchema.pre('save', function updateIsPassed(next) {
  // update the isPassed based on the totalScore obtained by the candidate.
  next();
});

export const CandidateQuesAnswer = mongoose.model('CandidateAnswer', CandidateQuesAnswerSchema);
```

Where I have used pre `save` hooks provided by `mongoose`, before saving the document and calculating the values to declare the candidate pass or fail.

Comment: I really appreatiate your effort this what I needed and I will be working out of this.

Comment: I m new to node mongo so I am having a little difficulty in understanding this.Step1: I have to ceate Question collection with questions and options like you did ,then I have to create a collection for correct answers having question id and correct option number right ?

Comment: answerOptions: {
    type: [AnswerOptionSchema], 
is and array with the properties of AnswerOptionSchema . right?

Comment: Yes UJ, and also better to analyze on paper first if you are facing difficulties.

Comment: for the answer options, add four options at once for each question.

Comment: validator: function(value: any) {
SyntaxError: Unexpected token : 

DI have to require any schema validator modeule to schema file?

Comment: no, see the docs you will get a better understanding of this: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators

Comment: yes fixed like this validate: [arrayLimit, 'Answer options should be 4.'] function arrayLimit(val) {
  return val.length === 4;
}

Comment: now i want to generate question set . If the questions collections 100 pre loaded questions.I have to generate 3 set of 12 questions what i am trying to create is an api to get these questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179728/discussion-between-shivam-pandey-and-uj-india).

Answer (score 1):

Please continue with:

```
CandidateQuesAnswerSchema.pre('save', function updateTotalScore(next) , 

CandidateQuesAnswerSchema.pre('save', function updateIsPassed(next)
```

Functions

Answer (score -5):

Here is basic syntax you can use:

First You need To require the mongoose like this:
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

Then You need To create Schema like this:

var studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
});

And Final Step is to create a model like this:
var student = mongoose.model('student', studentSchema);

That's all:
This is the basic structure.
:)

Comment: Thanks for replying.If you read my question I needed idea of modelling the schema as I am aware of the basic syntax.It will be helpful if you could help me by giving idea of how the questions,answers and result collections should be like.I ll be posting another question if I am stuck while coding