# Mongoose Schema planning: using ObjectID reference or using array of type: [otherSchema]?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, schema

I'm currently planning out the database structure for an app I'm building, and something in [this linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52229660/8054843) raised some questions for me.

In the structure that Shivam proposed, he sometimes references another collection directly, in other words within one Schema he defines the type of a field to be an array of another schema type. Example:

```
import { Schema } from "mongoose";
import { QuestionSchema } from "./question-schema";
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

export const QuestionSetSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  questionSet: {
    type: [QuestionSchema],
    validate: {
      validator: function(value: any) {
        return value.length === 12;
      },
      message: 'Question set must be 12.'
    }
  },
}, {
  timestamps: true
});
```

In other cases, he only uses an ObjectID reference to another schema/collection:

```
export const CandidateSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String, // you can store other candidate related information here.
  totalAttempt: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
    validate: {
      validator: function(value: number) {
        return value === 3;
      },
      message: 'You have already done three attempts.'
    }
  },
  candidateQuestionAnswers: {
    type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    ref: 'CandidateQuesAnswer'
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});
```

What are the use cases for each of the above? Does the "type:[otherSchema]" method actually embed instances of that collection or does it only provide their properties to the Schema they are called from?

Comment: this may help: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-ref This is the option that populate looks at to determine the foreign collection it should query https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: This makes sense for the ObjectID ref method, which is what I was previously familiar with. The question that the above post/answer raised for me was when I would use something like "type: [otherSchema]" instead of "type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId] ref: otherSchema"